# how to handle doInbackGround exception?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

i have an asyncTask that downloads an image. sometimes it can't download and give this exception `java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()`

Now i want to handle this and when it occurs stop downloading (because i create a notification bar in `onPreExecute` that show download progress) and Toast a message that download not completed!

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    mNotifyManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);   //.... to create a notification 
    }
 downloadPackage(IMG_DIR_URL);//my function to download an imagedo some stuff
 return null;
}
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
    // setting progress bar on notification area
    //fore example mBuilder.setProgress(100, progress[0], false);
}
```

Comment: Post your code so easy to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In similar case as of yours, I opted following approach:

```
   private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
     Exception exception = null; 
        protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
            try{
               //downloading code here..
             }catch(SomeException e){
              exception = e;
             }
             return totalSize;
         }


         protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
             if(exception!=null){
               // show toast.
               // cancel async task. (this.cancel())

             }else{
               // no exception while downloading, check for result and take corresponding action on result
             }
         }

 }
```

Comment: thanks. but it returns exception after 2 or 3 minutes (but progress bar stopped after about 30 seconds how can i Toast if downlaoding stopped )

Comment: Then you need to figure out why progress bar stopped. try logging in async task, and your posted code in not sufficient enough to detect the problem.

Answer (score 0):

just put your code in try/catch block and in catch block you can handle exception and app will never crash: use the below code to handle and get the error,it will give you the methid and class name also the line number of exception.

```
try {
        //do your stuff
    } catch (Exception e) {
        for (int i = 0; i < e.getStackTrace().length; i++) {
            StackTraceElement oStackTace = e.getStackTrace()[i];
            String ClassName = oStackTace.getClassName();
            String MethodName = oStackTace.getMethodName();
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
            String exceptionAsString = sw.toString();
            Log.d("Class Name: " + ClassName + " Method Name: "
                    + MethodName, exceptionAsString);
    }
    }
```